# How to get rid of unwanted space between tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

I have a page with two large tables, one positioned above the other:

http://www.sportsmogul.com/Encyclopedia/2007/BOS/index.html

In my editor (Dreamweaver), there is no space between the tables.

But in Chrome, there is a gap of about 10 pixels (the blue space where the background shows through, between the top "navbar" and the rest of the page).

Would like to get rid of this gap.

Comment: Put your code here, or better, make a JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 5):

It appears that there is a `<br>` tag right inbetween the tables, I must say that while there is a tiny bit of doubt, I do believe that this is the culprit.

Please see Exhibit A:

[image]

Highlighted in blue, the `<br>` resides right inbetween the tables.

For more information about the `<br>` tag please see this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Elements

Comment: I don't see the <br> in my code. I have even opened it in Notepad and I can't find it. :(

Also, what editor are you using (in your screenshot)? Perhaps that would make it easier for me to find this alleged <br>...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `<br>` tag before the starting `<table>` tag of the tables. If you remove that, the space goes off in Chrome. Since Dreamweaver does not display non-display elements, you wouldn't have seen it during the source time.